# CoCreateInstance works great in Release but in debug doesn't

Tags: c++, debugging, dll, com

I'm newbie in COM and have a problem in debugging dll. In this code:

```
        _Check_return_ HRESULT CoCreateInstance(_In_ REFCLSID rclsid, _In_opt_ LPUNKNOWN pUnkOuter = NULL, _In_ DWORD dwClsContext = CLSCTX_ALL)  
throw()  
    {  
        ATLASSERT(p == NULL);  
        return ::CoCreateInstance(rclsid, pUnkOuter, dwClsContext, __uuidof(T), (void**)&p);  
    }
```

in return I have error R6034: an application has an attempt to load C runtime library incorrectly.

Plus: In output window of VS 2008 I noticed that debugging stops at certain message:

```
'OmpClimApp.exe': Loaded '\\omegaserver\omega\app32\OMEGA.DLL\RWUXThemeS.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
```

Where is an error?

Comment: The error is telling you that RWUXThemeS.dll was built without debug information and you cannot debug into this library. Can you step over this call instead of stepping into it?

Comment: "an application has an attempt to load C runtime library incorrectly" might indicate things like missing crt dlls or mixing debug/release runtimes. Use Dependency Walker to figure out the problem.

Comment: If I do step over I get error an application has an attempt to load C runtime library incorrectly.

Comment: Dependency Walker. Hmm. I'll try

Comment: The DLL is not built correctly, it is missing the required manifest.  You'll need to get help from the DLL owner.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the problem is mixing `Debug` and `Release` assembly versions of MS CRT libraries. `Microsoft.VC80.CRT` and `Microsoft.DebugVC80.CRT` assemblies use the same common publicKeyToken `"1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"` so they cannot be loaded simultaneously into single application.

In your case manifest of `RWUXThemeS.dll` refers to `Microsoft.VC80.CRT` but manifest of your application in `Debug` build refers to `Microsoft.DebugVC80.CRT`. Trying to load `RWUXThemeS.dll` causes the error which description actually is not correct, it shall be "Unable to load assembly which public key is already used by another assembly".

**Possible solution:** you need debug version of `RWUXThemeS.dll` to be linked to your application in debug build. Assuming its name is `RWUXThemeSD.dll`.

See [MSDN for more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235560%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (Community Content, main article doesn't look relevant to your problem).

`RWUXTheme` library is part of Rogue Wave Stingray Studio, see [documentation](http://www.roguewave.com/search.aspx?q=RWUXTheme).

Comment: In Modules window of VS2008 I found RWUXThemeSD.dll. It's with message "The module did not load a the default load address". In status of RWUXThemeSD.dll the same trouble "Binary was not built with debug information."

Comment: Refer to Rogue Wave Stingray Studio docs, maybe I was wrong and debug library name is different.

Comment: So for debug build you need that your app links to `RWUXThemeSD.dll` but not `RWUXThemeS.dll`. Check other DLLs if any, they must also follow this rule.